# From Web Client repo to Web Client, App Client, Utils/API

Tags: reactjs, git, react-native

I currently have a growing React JS project. Within the project I have a folder for my utils that include business logic and API calls.

The plan is to separate the the web client, the utils and a new react native based app client into three different projects. The web and app client will both make use of the same api calls and business logic.

What's the best way to go about splitting up the current project and how would I link everything? Is an NPM package the way to go or is there a way to do something similar within Github?

TL;DR: What's the best way to separate my utils folder into its own project and using it within my current web project?

Answer (score 0):

You could make an NPM package. That would work. However I found it is easier to use a symlinked folder. It's quicker, simpler, and plays better with dev and debug tools.

The downsides of an NPM package are:

- Getting build processes like `webpack` to work *and* give you nice source code maps for debugging is a headache.
- It's easier to get code-versioning issues.